# Interpolate array to constant density

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have been going in circles with this apparently simple issue for hours and I can't seem to find the answer.

The setup is straightforward: given an array of floats, interpolate extra points so that the resulting interpolated data is distributed with a constant (or approximately constant) density.

The standard interpolation works, but the density of the interpolated points is not constant at all (right plot):

[image]

I must be missing something obvious here because I'm sure this issue is not that complicated, and I've been struggling for too long now.

Any help is much appreciated.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([13.826, 13.608, 13.163, 13.034, 12.672, 12.126, 11.585, 11.192,
       10.609, 10.082,  9.67 ,  9.261,  9.175,  8.869,  8.408,  7.868,
        7.317,  6.827,  6.52 ,  6.375,  5.968,  5.601,  5.271,  5.242,
        4.961,  4.888,  4.661,  4.395,  4.376,  4.286,  4.105,  4.019,
        3.845,  3.785,  3.601,  3.371,  3.226,  3.156,  2.984,  2.96 ,
        2.931,  2.786,  2.757,  2.62 ,  2.554,  2.473,  2.464,  2.451,
        2.309,  2.196,  2.15 ,  2.061,  1.987,  1.907,  1.825,  1.803,
        1.721,  1.62 ,  1.595,  1.57 ,  1.462,  1.346,  1.334,  1.208,
        1.09 ,  1.033,  0.94 ,  0.874,  0.852,  0.857,  0.872,  0.884,
        0.889,  0.888,  0.9  ,  0.856,  0.756,  0.652,  0.567,  0.495,
        0.432,  0.378,  0.331,  0.293,  0.264,  0.244,  0.232,  0.228,
        0.228,  0.231,  0.239,  0.248,  0.261,  0.278,  0.308,  0.357,
        0.417,  0.495,  0.575,  0.59 ,  0.544,  0.465,  0.355,  0.246,
        0.138,  0.032, -0.032, -0.075, -0.139, -0.179, -0.28 , -0.38 ,
       -0.471, -0.565, -0.671, -0.772, -0.872, -0.974, -1.069, -1.164,
       -1.257, -1.169, -1.131, -1.084, -1.016, -0.936, -0.846, -0.748,
       -0.647, -0.546, -0.444, -0.348, -0.274, -0.159, -0.05 ,  0.091,
        0.145,  0.236,  0.318,  0.239,  0.105, -0.036, -0.168, -0.303,
       -0.304, -0.429, -0.571, -0.685, -0.704, -0.806, -0.849, -0.865,
       -0.835, -0.823, -0.892, -0.928, -0.978, -1.077, -1.156, -1.065,
       -1.153, -1.244, -1.332, -1.426, -1.523, -1.623, -1.722, -1.819,
       -1.918, -2.03 , -2.135, -2.233, -2.33 , -2.423, -2.516, -2.609,
       -2.7  , -2.791, -2.88 , -2.948, -3.913])

# Number of points to interpolate
N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
xp = np.linspace(0, 1, data.size)
# Interpolated data
d_interp = np.interp(t, xp, data)

plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(t, d_interp, label='Interpolated points')
plt.scatter(xp, data, s=4, label='Original data')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(122)
plt.hist(d_interp, 25, label='Density of interpolated data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: IIUC I don't think this is the function you want. It interpolates to produce a fixed number of coordinates between two consecutive data points. I suspect the density histogram of your raw data will look the same?

Comment: The histogram is plotting exactly what it should. The maximum density of points is around 0.8 even in the interpolated curve

Comment: Yes, the histogram and my raw data are distributed as shown. The problem is not the histogram. The problem is that I want to interpolate extra points into my raw data so that *their* distribution is approximately constant, ie: a rather flat histogram.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll have a think if I know if there's a better function or whether this can be adapted. I'm not sure yet whether I'm convinced this is substantially different to some kind of curve fitting so perhaps we're thinking along the wrong track

Comment: So, in other words, you want your interpolated points to be distributed evenly on y-axis?

Comment: @Georgy pretty much, yes, It doesn't even need to be *exactly* constant density, I'll take a somewhat flat distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sample y points instead of x points. Sampling y points is easy:

```
d_interp = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), N)
```

Now you want to interpolate (y, x) instead of (x,y). You could try this, but this won't work:

```
t = np.interp(d_interp, data, xp)
```

The problem is that interpolating the corresponding x points: `np.interp` expects your `x` to be monotonally increasing. In fact, by choosing a random `y` point in your chart (say `x=0`), you have at 2 or 3 corresponding x points. Therefore, for each `y`, you don't know what `x` to choose.

The solution I suggest is, given your function is mostly decreasing, to filter your sample set by using a mask:

```
mask = np.append(True, np.diff(data) < 0)   #first points, plus all monotonally decreasing y points
d_interp = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), N)
t = np.interp(d_interp, data[mask][::-1], xp[mask][::-1])
```

[image: output]

Comment: Although this looks good when plotted, I can not see how I would obtain from this the interpolated values in `y`, which is what I want.

Comment: if you want to obtain homogeneously distributed values in y, you need to sample in y and obtain the corresponding x values from the inverse function (or interpolation)